# maven configuration to aggregate multiple services + restEasy + spring

Tags: spring, rest, maven, resteasy

I am using spring and restEasy for development of restful services.

In the project, the number of services is large and continue to grow, I am looking for Maven configurations to break the task into small modules. All of these services will have same web context. The idea is to have only a small set of service, business logic and dao logic in a module, and then combine the modules into the final project.

A constraint in the project is to distribute resteasy annotated classes in separate module. I am not sure if this automatically implies that they all should have war packaging.. think not.

The example I've seen so far are where the classes with jax-rs annotations are in just one web-packaged module.

Any suggestions on how to distribute classes with jax-rd annotations in separate module such that they can eventually be aggregated to form restful services with same web context

Comment: What's stopping you from using multiple modules?

Answer (score 0):

Parent pom looks like

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>application</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Greg Application</name>

    <modules>
            <module>projecta</module>
            <module>projectb</module>
            <module>projectc</module>
    </modules>
```

The the pom for projectb can use projecta as a dependency as so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>projecta</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```